# Can I generate a table of contents from a pdf?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

Let's say I have a pdf which was created with latex using `\section`s, but the creator did not generate bookmarks for the pdf using the `hyperref` package, and I do not have access to the latex source. Is there a way to automatically generate the table of contents from the pdf?

To be clear, I mean the kind of table of contents that lives somewhere in the metadata of the pdf, which most pdf readers let you view in a side window.

Comment: I've never heard anything about automagically creating bookmarks.

Comment: This is more of a PDF question than a LaTeX question.  Even if you had the anchor names (which are available in ASCII), what would you do with them?

Comment: I think this is also a Latex question because we can assume that the pdf was generated with default Latex classes. Generating a table of contents for arbitrary pdfs would be pretty complicated, but my thinking was that pdfs generated from article class Latex for example should be predictable enough that the section headers could be scraped.